# GStreamer: Mjpeg to H264 with hardware encoding

Tags: pi-4, webcam, gstreamer, h264

I'm having trouble with my pipeline for taking mjpeg video from a USB webcam and encoding it into H264 with the hardware encoding through GStreamer on a PI4 (ubuntu 22.04, but I have tried pi os 64 and 32 bit as well, same results). I believe this is possible as it was done [here](https://codecalamity.com/raspberry-pi-hardware-encoding-speed-test/) with ffmpeg and also [here](https://discuss.bluerobotics.com/t/integration-of-mjpg-format-camera/3932) with gstreamer but software encoding. I see mention of omx encoder here, but I read [here](https://www.hackster.io/news/chris-griffith-puts-the-raspberry-pi-s-hardware-h-264-encoder-through-its-paces-1d804e538d9e) that this is an older impementatin?
This pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,type=video,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.146 port=5600`

works, but I believe it uses software encoding with x264enc. I believe that you use v4l2h264enc for hardware encoding, but

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,type=video,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! v4l2h264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.146 port=5600`

does not work:

```
Additional debug info:
../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2videoenc.c(844): gst_v4l2_video_enc_handle_frame (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/v4l2h264enc:v4l2h264enc0:
Maybe be due to not enough memory or failing driver
Execution ended after 0:00:00.387990762
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Am I wrong with how hardware encoding works? I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to use it.